# Yii2 component pass data to __construct

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a lib which I want to use as component. In config file I set it like that:

```
'components' => [
    'superLib' => [
        'class' => 'SuperLib'
         // '__construct' => [$first, $second] Maybe Yii 2 have property for this 
    ],
],
```

How I can pass data to `__construct()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the times you don't have to override `__construct()`.

Pretty much every object in Yii 2 is extended from [yii\base\Object](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-object.html) which has assignment properties through configurational array feature.

Components is extended from [yii\base\Component](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-component.html), the latter is extended from `yii\base\Object` too. So in your example along with class name (note that you should provide full class name with namespace while in your example it's in the root namespace) you can pass any properties / values pairs:

```
'components' => [
    'superLib' => [
        'class' => 'SuperLib'
        'firstProperty' => 'firstPropertyValue',
        'secondProperty' => 'secondPropertyValue',
    ],
],
```

Sometimes you need to use [init()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-object.html#init%28%29-detail) method (for example for checking if values have valid types and throw some kind of exceptions, for setting default values, etc.):

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init(); // Call parent implementation;

    ...
}
```

Here is some useful info from official docs:

> Besides the property feature, Object also introduces an important
>   object initialization life cycle. In particular, creating an new
>   instance of Object or its derived class will involve the following
>   life cycles sequentially:
>
> - the class constructor is invoked;
> - object properties are initialized according to the given configuration;
> - the `init()` method is invoked.
>
> In the above, both Step 2 and 3 occur at the end of the class
>   constructor. It is recommended that you perform object initialization
>   in the `init()` method because at that stage, the object configuration
>   is already applied.
>
> In order to ensure the above life cycles, if a child class of Object
>   needs to override the constructor, it should be done like the
>   following:

```
public function __construct($param1, $param2, ..., $config = [])
{
    ...

    parent::__construct($config); 
}
```

> That is, a `$config` parameter (defaults to `[]`) should be declared as
>   the last parameter of the constructor, and the parent implementation
>   should be called at the end of the constructor.

If nevertheless want to use additional parameters in `__construct` you can do it like that:

```
'components' => [
    'superLib' => [
        'class' => 'app\components\SuperLib',
        ['firstParamValue', 'secondParamValue'],
    ],
],
```

You can find it in official docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-baseyii.html#createObject%28%29-detail) in third example.

Comment: Brilliant answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `__construct()` instead of `__contruct` as configuration key:

```
'components' => [
    'superLib' => [
        'class' => namespace\of\SomeClass::class
         '__construct()' => [$first, $second],
    ],
],
```